# multiple definition in linking

Tags: c, linker

I'm a beginner into Linking, lets say I have two .c files

file1.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.c"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int a = function2();
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

and file2.c is

```
int function2() 
{ 
    return 2018;
}
```

when I compiled, there is a linker error which is multiple definition of function2, but I only define function once in file2.c?

Comment: `#include "file2.c"` is a whole wrong approach,

Comment: Function *definitions* (implementation) in source files. Function *declarations* in header files. Include header files, build with source files.

Comment: If you `#include "file2.c"` you don't need to compile `file2.c` separately and link it with `file1.o` — the information in `file2.o` is already in `file1.o`.  What's more normal is to `#include "file2.h"` in both `file2.c` and `file1.c`, and then you need to compile and link both source files into one executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `#include "file2.c"` effectively incorporates the contents of `file2.c` into `file1.c`. Then `file1.c` is compiled as if it contains:

```
int function2() 
{ 
    return 2018;
}
```

Those lines **define** `function2`; they tell the compiler “Here is `function2`, create code for it.” Because those lines effectively appear in both `file1.c` and `file2.c`, your program has two copies of `function2`.

Instead, you should create `file2.h` that contains:

```
int function2();
```

That line tells the compiler “There exists a function called `function2`, but its definition is somewhere else.”

Then, in `file1.c`, use `#include "file2.h"` instead of `#include "file2.c"`. This will tell the compiler, while `file1.c` is being compiled, what it needs to know to compile a call to `function2`. The compiler will have the **declaration** it needs, but it will not have the **definition**, which is not needed in `file1.c`.

Also, in `file2.c`, insert `#include "file2.h"`. Then `file2.c` will contain both a declaration of `function2` (from `file2.h`) and a definition of `function2` (from the actual lines in `file2.c`). The purpose of this is so the compiler can see both the declaration and the definition while it is compiling `file2.c`, so it can warn you if there is a typographical error that makes them incompatible.

Additionally, in C, you should use `int function2(void)` rather than `int function2()`. For historic reasons, the latter leaves the parameters unspecified. Using `(void)` tells the compiler there are no parameters.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. but if I don't insert  #include "file2.h". into file2.c, it is still OK to complier, so why I need to  insert  #include "file2.h" since #include "file2.h" already in file1.c?

Comment: @amjad: The purpose of this is so the compiler can see both the declaration and the definition while it is compiling `file2.c`, so it can warn you if there is a typographical error that makes them incompatible.

Comment: hi, could you give me an example of  typographical error that makes them incompatible, please? thank you so much

Comment: `file2.h` could say `int foo(void);`, while `file2.c` says `float foo(void) …`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a header file, "file2.h", with:

```
int function2(void);
```

and a file "file2.c" with the function: "file2.h" with:

```
#include "file2.h"

int function2(void) 
{ 
    return 2018;
    ...
}
```

Then in your main you have to include the header with:

```
#include "file2.h"
```

Keep care that all those files should be in the same folder to avoid any link problem

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int a = function2();
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

file2.h:

```
extern int function2(void);
```

and file2.c is

```
#include "file2.h"

int function2(void) 
{ 
    return 2018;
}
```

And then link it together.

Comment: My personal opinion: You should remove the `extern` from `file2.h`, it's not wrong, but not necessary

Comment: @Jabberwocky: not everyone would agree with you — for instance, I don't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I prefer to see `extern int function2(void)l;` in the header. I accept that there are people who prefer not to see `extern`; I prefer to see `extern`, if only for symmetry with the `extern` declaration of those global variables that sometimes have to be declared in headers, where the `extern` is crucial.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK, but we agree the `extern` keyword on function declarations is purely decorative, it doesn't change anything, does it?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Attached to a function declaration, the keyword `extern` is optional — yes.  It is, IMO, clearer when present, but not everyone agrees with me (any more than everyone agrees with you).